# Write a recursive function in python that duplicates each character in a string

Tags: python, function, recursion, duplicates, repeat

For example the input would be "abc" and the function should return "aabbcc".

I'm new to recursive functions and am really confused about them.

Comment: What is your confusion?

Comment: @deceze When we show examples in class there's usually some variable that counts down towards a bottom limit that ends the function.  I don't see how to do that for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bottom limit" here is when the string (or list or tuple...) passed in is empty - in which case you just return it, which will end the recursion:

```
def recdup(seq):
    if not seq:
        return seq
    head, tail = seq[0:1], seq[1:]
    return (head * 2) + recdup(tail)
```

Comment: This is perfect, but I'm not sure what the "if not seq:" is doing.  Does that statement return true if it's an empty string and false if it is a string?

Comment: This is really Python 101 - https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Answer (score 1):

```
#iterate through x, store each value twice in y, print y joined by nothing
x = 'abc'
y=[i*2 for i in x]
print ''.join(y)
```

Comment: This works but it's not like recursive is it? I think this solution is iterative.

Comment: Certainly the most pythonic solution, but the OP asked for a recursive one...